# how to show/hide a few link images in an interval using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show some link images in 3 second time intervals but after the first image fades out nothing shows up, any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="fadein">
  <a href=""><img src="/media/home-content.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  <a href=""><img src="/media/Banners/images/denim.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

jquery

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.fadein a img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){
          jQuery('.fadein a:first-child img').fadeOut(3000)
             .parent().next('a img').fadeIn()
             .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
          3000);
    });

});
```

UPDATE

Just change the code to

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.fadein a:gt(0) img').hide();
        setInterval(function(){
          jQuery('.fadein a:first-child img').fadeOut(3000)
             .parent().next('a').children('img').fadeIn()
             .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
          10000);
    });
```

Comment: Once it fades out, it will get hidden. Dont you need to show it again.

Answer (score 1):

Hey man try this: http://jsfiddle.net/gRHPA/2/

Hope this helps!

**code**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('.fadein a:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function(){
    jQuery('.fadein a:first-child')
        .fadeOut()
        .next('a')
        .fadeIn()
        .end()
        .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 3000);
​
```

Comment: If you set `.fadeOut(0)` and `.fadeIn(500)` then they won't appear on the screen at the same time (for direct replacement rather than temporary 'stacking').

Comment: hey @RobinGower see working here: http://jsfiddle.net/gRHPA/3/ but why would you do that OP socially wants 3000, demo should help

Comment: Other way around: http://jsfiddle.net/gRHPA/4/
It still cycles every 3 seconds, it just doesn't have two images visible at the same time (so the fade in/out don't overlap).

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function() {
    var intervalId;
    var $previousAnchor;
    var $anchor;
    var $firstAnchor = $(".fadein a").first();

    $anchor = $firstAnchor;
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        $anchor.fadeIn();

        if (typeof($previousAnchor) != "undefined") {
            $previousAnchor.hide();
        }

        $previousAnchor = $anchor;

        if (typeof($anchor) == "undefined" || $anchor.next()[0] == undefined) {
            $anchor = $firstAnchor;
        }
        else {
            $anchor = $anchor.next();
        };
    }, 1000);
});
```

Note the use of caching to increase performance. I also added a performance test to compare the provided solutions I could get to work.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7MFb/)
See [**Performance Test**](http://jsperf.com/varitions-of-setinterval)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [JQuery carousel Plugin](http://thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Easier, faster with this

css:

```
.fadein a{
    display:none;
}​
```

js:

```
var current = null;
$(function(){
    $('.fadein').each(function(){
        var context = this;
        current = $('a',this).first().show();
        setInterval(function(){
            $(current).hide();
            var next = $(current).next('a');
            if(next.length == 0)
                next = $('a',context).first();
            current = $(next).show();          
        }, 1000);
    });
});​
```

working fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/C4uER/

Comment: just in case you have more than one carousel div. basically here you just need a div with fadein class and anchor tag inside.